# How to count and produce code if there is more than one occurency in a table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page that dynamically looks for comments and replies in a databes and produce code accordingly. Now, i want to count the number of replies per comment (`comment_id` in the table below) and if they are more than 3 show `"There are XX replies"` else show all the replies.

The table of replies looks like this

```
+---------------------+----+---------+------------------+------------+
| date                | id | user_id | reply            | comment_id |
+---------------------+----+---------+------------------+------------+
| xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx |  1 |      01 | adasdasdasdasdas |          8 |
| xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx |  2 |      02 | test             |          8 |
| xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx |  3 |      03 | m  no            |          8 |
| xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx |  4 |      03 | mno              |          8 |
| xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx |  5 |      05 | hehe             |         10 |
+---------------------+----+---------+------------------+------------+
```

`id` is the id of the reply

`user_id` is the user who wrote the comment

`comment_id` is the id of the father'reply (a.k.a. the comment)

What i've tried so far is:

```
$querys = "SELECT * FROM replies 
            WHERE comment_id = {$writeComment['comment_id']} 
            ORDER BY date DESC;";

$findReplies = mysqli_query($_SESSION['connection'], $querys);

while ($reply = mysqli_fetch_assoc($findReplies)) {
    $countReplies = "SELECT * FROM replies
                    GROUP BY comment_id
                    HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT comment_id ) > 3;";

$moreThanThree = mysqli_query($_SESSION['connection'], $countReplies);

if(!$moreThanThree){
    // code for lass than 3 replies
} else {
    // there are xx replies
    // show  all replies
}
```

Comment: what did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i managed to solve the problem, partially thank to @Gouda Elalfy:

```
while ($reply = mysqli_fetch_assoc($findReplies)) {

    $querya = "SELECT comment_id, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM replies 
           WHERE comment_id = {$writeComment['comment_id']}) 
           AS reply_count FROM replies";


    $findHowMany = mysqli_query($_SESSION['connection'], $querya);
    $moreThanThree = mysqli_fetch_assoc($findHowMany);


        if($moreThanThree['reply_count'] < 3){
            //print comment
        } elseif (isset($prevId)){
           if(prevID != $reply['id']){
           // print "there are xx comments"
           break;
           }
        }

    $prevId = $reply['id'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a group by query to find the count of replies. Then using these results you can display the text accordingly.

```
SELECT comment_id, count(*) FROM replies GROUP BY comment_id
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this query:

> select reply, (select count(*) from replies replies_inner where replies_inner.comment_id = replies.comment_id) as reply_count from replies

then you can loop through php:

```
$previuos_comment=$rows[0]['comment_id'];
foreach($rows as $row) {
$reply_count =$row['reply_count '];
if($reply_count>3) {
echo 'xxxxxx';
} else {
if($previuos_comment==$row['comment_id']) {
echo $row['reply'];
}
$previuos_comment=$row['comment_id'];
}

}
```